# How to specify a DNS cache server that FireFox uses in Selenium(Python)?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, firefox, dns

Now, I'm running FireFox using Selenium(Python).

I want to configure a DNS cache server(1.1.1.1 or 8.8.8.8 or self-hosted-DNS) that FireFox uses when running my program.

On Web FireFox, we can change DNS cache server to use like the following image.

[image]

I think that FireFox use a local provider written in `/etc/resolv.conf` by default, but I don't edit `/etc/resolv.conf` to change DNS cache server. I want to do the same thing by specifying resolver when running program.

How to realize the above?

I want you to help me!
Thanks.